# Fixing Syntax For using SQL insert in go

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, syntax

I am getting an error when I try to use ? arguments when using the go sql library.

Whe I do something like:

```
_, err = db.Query(
    `INSERT INTO user_account (username, password_hash) VALUES ("username", 'passwordhash');`,
```

everything works fine.

But when I do the following:

```
_, err = db.Query(
    `INSERT INTO user_account (username, password_hash) VALUES (?, 'passwordhash');`,
    `'username'`)
```

I get the error:

```
pq: syntax error at or near ","
```

How can I fix this error? I suspect it has something to do with the single quotes around the variables.

If it matters, I'm using postgreq with the pq driver.

Comment: have you tried `username` instead of `'username'`? The `qp` package will escape the value by itself.

Comment: What is happening if you use double quotes for username like:
, err = db.Query(
    `INSERT INTO user_account (username, password_hash) VALUES (?, 'passwordhash');`,
    `"username"`)

Comment: On the website I see in the examples no `?` but `$1`, `$2`, etc. Maybe try that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I fixed this by using the $1 syntax (thanks TehSphinx).

Comment: Once this was fixed, I had a double quote issue as well. The string "'username'" was being added isntead of the string "username".

Comment: Sorry, I should close this but I don't have enough rep to post an answer.